Initial and boundary conditions for parabolic PDEs
Consider a parabolic PDE of the form
\begin{align}
\phi_t=f\left(\phi,\phi_x,\phi_{xx} \right),
\end{align}
with $f$ some reasonable function, and if needed for the argument below linear $\phi_{xx}$.
It is usually stressed that on a domain $[0,L_t]\times[ 0,L_x]$ one needs to provide the three functions
\begin{align}
\phi(x,0)\:,\phi(0,t)\:,\phi(L_x,t)
\end{align}
to obtain a unique solution. However, if we just give $\phi(x,0)$ from the equation we have that, for some small $\epsilon$,
\begin{align}
\phi(x,\epsilon)=\phi(x,0)+\epsilon f\left(\phi(x,0),\phi_x(x,0),\phi_{xx}(x,0) \right)
\end{align}
with the r.h.s completely know; from this $\phi(x,\epsilon)$ we can continue growing the solution until $t=L_t$, so it would mean that the solution is uniquely determined out of $\phi(x,0)$ only. Is there a flaw in the argument ?

The given approximate argument boils down to the fact that at the moment $t=0$   the time derivative depends indeed on the initial condition and function $f$ only:
$$
\phi_t(x,0)=f\left(\phi(x,0),\phi_x(x,0),\phi_{xx}(x,0) \right).
$$
But knowing only the first derivative at one point is not enough to reproduce the solution at any moment of time $t>0$. And solutions indeed depend on boundary conditions.
